# How to remove .NET Remoting Fatal problem :Exception

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, ipc, publish-subscribe

I am implementing Publisher/Subscriber pattern via .NET Remoting. My publisher is waiting for incoming requests on its url. At its side remoting environment configures properly and no problem at all.

At subscriber's end when I make some subscriptions from its side to publisher, it hangs out. I mean program hangs and console shows nothing , and it gone away, no exception here. When I disconnect publisher it now it resume's and follow processing and throws exceptions with stack Trace:

Here's the stack trace..

```
**System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004
005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Server stack trace:

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
 SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 of
fset, Int32 size)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadFromSocket(Byte[] buffe
r, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 o
ffset, Int32 count)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ReadAndMatchFourBytes(Byte[
] buffer)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpSocketHandler.ReadAndMatchPreamble
()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpSocketHandler.ReadVersionAndOperat
ion(UInt16& operation)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientSocketHandler.ReadHeaders()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage
(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITranspor
tHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMess
age(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at DTFSharedObjects.IRemoteEventsPublisher.AddSubscription(Type type, String
url)
   at AgentTestRunner.CTestRunner.createSubscription() in d:\dtfsourcecode\dtf_b
ackend\agentsourcecode\sourcecode\runnercode\testrunner\testrunner.cpp:line 438**
```

Regards
Usman

Comment: i think more data (as in code) on whats going on on the server is needed here.

Comment: Have you turned off the Windows firewalls as a test?

Comment: I would run a packet trace to find out what's actually going over the network.

Comment: my best bet here: it's a firewall or router problem: when an event should fire, remoting tries to connect back to the other side through a new socket and that is often not possible.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings? Disable the firewall and try again